# A romance anime where the girl eats a lot of food in order not to stand out

Tags: blue-spring-ride

This anime is my head. It's a romance anime and didn't seem that old. It starts with a girl who is kinda a tomboy and she eats a lot of food in order not to stand out. I remember one scene where a guy says that she looks pretty and then she stuffs her face with food, also her friends said bad stuff about a shy girl in her class. She sees her long lost crush walking on her road and he asks her why she considers those people as 'friends' and she listens to him and stands up for the shy girl and becomes friends with her. She is seen crying and the guy hugs her from the window....

I just can't remember what its called! So frustrating.. Please help.

Comment: For future reference, please note when you saw the anime to help narrow down the list of candidates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like **Ao Haru Ride** aka **Blue Spring Ride** [(MyAnimeList page)](http://myanimelist.net/anime/21995/Ao_Haru_Ride).

Description from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Spring_Ride):

> Futaba Yoshioka wants to "reset" her life. In junior high, girls ostracized Futaba because too many junior high boys liked her. The only boy Futaba liked, Kou Tanaka, moved away before she could tell him how she felt. Now in high school, Futaba is determined to be unladylike so her new friends will not become jealous of her. While living her new life contentedly, she meets Kou again, but he now uses the name Kou Mabuchi and has a cold attitude. He tells her that he liked her too in junior high, but feels differently now.

[image]